# How to set up Fusion App with npm instead of yarn?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fusionjs

I don't have experience with yarn because I have been using npm till now. While creating a fusion app, I am not able to install  *npm install --force @fusion/core @fusion/react @fusion/cli @fusion/tokens react react-dom* . I get errors liker eslint dependency not matched or this - >

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fusion%2fcore - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@fusion/core@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

I have tried everything yet nothing seems to work.

I want to set up a normal app to start working with React and Redux